# Keycloak-gatekeeper cannot decode "state" due to "illegal base64 data"

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

I am getting this error from keycloak-gatekeeper when trying to access protected resources

```
unable to decode the state parameter    {"state": "8d07f10b-d096-4241-8a42-9f169de11352", "error": "illegal base64 data at input byte 8"}
```

Here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  keycloak-proxy:
    image: "keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper"
    environment:
     - PROXY_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:3000
     - PROXY_DISCOVERY_URL=http://keycloak.example.com:8181/auth/realms/realmcom
     - PROXY_CLIENT_ID=webapp
     - PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET=0b57186c-e939-48ff-aa17-cfd3e361f65e
     - PROXY_UPSTREAM_URL=http://test-server:8000
    ports:
      - "8282:3000"
    command:
      - "--verbose"
      - "--enable-refresh-tokens=true"
      - "--enable-default-deny=true"
      - "--resources=uri=/*"
      - "--enable-session-cookies=true"
      - "--encryption-key=AgXa7xRcoClDEU0ZDSH4X0XhL5Qy2Z2j"
  test-server:
    image: "test-server"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug - https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper/pull/433#issuecomment-443123758. Could you please file a Jira (https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK), add the affected version and steps to reproduce the issue?